# Pass a RenderWindow object of SFML to a template function

Tags: c++, templates, sfml, template-meta-programming

I am a newbie C++ programmer, and I am not a professional. I am so confused with the template in C++.

I was working with SFML and I could create a window and handle it. In the next step, I decided to write a template function to handle the close signal when it is generated. but my code doesn't compile. where is the problem?

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
void EventHandler(T& window) {
    std::cout << "Close event is made." << std::endl;
    window.close();
    std::cout << "Window is closed succesfully." << std::endl;
    break;
}

int main()
{
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(512, 512), "SMFL Tutorial", sf::Style::Default);
    sf::Event events;

    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        while (window.pollEvent(events))
        {
            switch (events.type)
            {
            case events.Closed:
                EventHandler(window);
            default:
                std::cout << "Unkown Events are creating." << std::endl;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you got `error: break statement not within loop or switch` or similar as compiler error, you need to just remove `break` from EventHandler. [break](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/break)

Comment: Please edit in the complete error message from your compiler, this will make help *much* easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to move the break statement from your function to case in the switch and properly use the `sf::Event::EventType` enum :

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
void EventHandler(T& window) {
    std::cout << "Close event is made." << std::endl;
    window.close();
    std::cout << "Window is closed succesfully." << std::endl;
    /// break; <- From here
}

int main()
{
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(512, 512), "SMFL Tutorial", sf::Style::Default);
    sf::Event events;

    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        while (window.pollEvent(events))
        {
            switch (events.type)
            {
            case sf::Event::Closed:
                EventHandler(window);
                break; /// <- To here
            default:
                std::cout << "Unkown Events are creating." << std::endl;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Moreover, why do you need a template function? Your `EventHandler` function can take a reference to a `sf::window` to work either with `sf::Window` and `sf::RenderWindow` :

```
void EventHandler(sf::Window& window) {
    std::cout << "Close event is made." << std::endl;
    window.close();
    std::cout << "Window is closed succesfully." << std::endl;
}
```